# react redux updating state of an object with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When my component mounts I get from an API and when successful my state looks like this,

```
    {
        "brief":"No brief given",
        "tasks":[
            {
                "_id":"5c74ffc257a059094cf8f3c2",
                "task":"87 Development Task 7",
                "project":"5c7458abd2fa91567f4e4f03",
                "date_created":"2019-02-26T08:58:42.260Z",
                "__v":0
            }
        ],
        "_id":"5c7458abd2fa91567f4e4f03",
        "owner":{
            "_id":"5c5af553eea087426cd5f9b9",
            "name":"Test test",
            "email":"test@test.com",
            "avatar":"placeholder.jpg",
            "created_at":"2019-02-06T14:55:15.321Z",
            "__v":0
        },
        "name":"87 Development Project 1",
        "status":"Pending",
        "slug":"87-development-project-1",
        "created_at":"2019-02-25T21:05:47.643Z",
        "__v":0
   }
```

What I am wanting to mark a task as complete, but I am confused over my reducer and action, the flow is the user clicks a button with fires the action, which posts to my api, which responds with an updated task object. However I am confused as to how I go about moving that updated task object into my state as the object is within an array within the state? Can anyone help me out?

This is my action,

```
import axios from "axios";

import { COMPLETE_TASK } from "./types";

// Set logged in user
export const completeTask = id => dispatch => {
  axios.post(`/api/tasks/complete`, { id }).then(res => {
    dispatch({
      type: COMPLETE_TASK,
      payload: res.data
    });
  });
};
```

And this is my reducer,

```
import { COMPLETE_TASK } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = { project: { tasks: [], owner: {} } };

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case COMPLETE_TASK:
      return {
        ...state,
        ????
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Now my feeling is that my initial state will clear any previous state? secondly how do I move the returned payload into the correct task object?

Comment: reducers can be made to work on smaller "slices" of state then composed together using [redux.combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)

Comment: so when a task is marked as completed, does it go to a `done` field in your state or you add a new attribute `done: true` in your task? do you want `tasks` field to be just containing all pending tasks?

Answer (score 0):

What does the response from your API `/api/tasks/complete` look like ? Is your API supposed to complete a task or retrieve a list of tasks ?

Anyway, you usually would use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in your reducers, e.g. if your API is for marking a task as complete and returns the id of the task that has been properly marked as completed, then your reducer would maybe look like this :

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case COMPLETE_TASK:
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: state.tasks.filter((task) => {
          return task.id !== action.taskToCompleteId
        })
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: there are just assumptions that `tasks` will just contain all pending tasks. however, it isn't clear yet where to put the completed task or marking the task as completed will just add a `done:true` to the task. So I suggest we could provide a better answer if we clarify first to clear assumptions.